# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 's' in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I currenlt have a piece of code which I'm trying to get into airflow.

The code takes data from a table and preforms the functions in the def map_manufacturer_model and outputs it into bigquery table.

I know the code works on my pc but, when I'm moving it to airflow I get the error:

***TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 's'***

Can anyone offer any guidance on this as I'm pretty stuck now!

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from google.cloud import bigquery
from airflow import models

client = bigquery.Client()

bqclient = bigquery.Client()

# Output table for dataframe
table_id = "Staging"

# Dataframe Code
query_string = """
SELECT * FROM `Staging`
"""
gasdata= (
    bqclient.query(query_string)
        .result()
        .to_dataframe(
        create_bqstorage_client=True,
    ))

manufacturers = {'G4F0': 'FLN', 'G4F1': 'FLN', 'G4F9': 'FLN', 'G4K0': 'HWL', 'E6S1': 'LPG', 'E6S2': 'LPG'}

meter_models = {'G4F0': {'1': 'G4SZV-1', '2': 'G4SZV-2'},
                'G4F9': {'': 'G4SZV-1'},
                'G4F1': {'': 'G4SDZV-2'},
                'G4K0': {'': 'BK-G4E'},
                'E6S1': {'': 'E6VG470'},
                'E6S2': {'': 'E6VG470'},
                }


def map_manufacturer_model(s):
    s = str(s)
    model = ''
    try:
        manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
        for k, m in meter_models[s[:4]].items():
            if s[-4:].startswith(k):
                model = m
                break
    except KeyError:
        manufacturer = ''

    return pd.Series({'NewMeterManufacturer': manufacturer,
                      'NewMeterModel': model
                      })


gas_data[['NewMeterManufacturer', 'NewMeterModel']] = gas_data['NewSerialNumber'].apply(map_manufacturer_model)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    # Specify a (partial) schema. All columns are always written to the
    # table. The schema is used to assist in data type definitions.
    schema=[
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    gas_data, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
print('Loaded DATAFRAME into BQ TABLE')


default_dag_args = {'owner': 'Owner',
                    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 15),
                    'retries': 1,
                    }

with models.DAG('test_dag',
                schedule_interval='0 8 * * *',
                default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    map_manufacturer_model_function = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='map_manufacturer_model_function',
        python_callable=map_manufacturer_model
    )
```

Comment: Please paste the whole traceback of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you actually call the PythonOperator you are not passing in the `s` argument.
You can add the op_kwargs, to the arguments passed as part of the call as below:

```
map_manufacturer_model_function = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='map_manufacturer_model_function',
        python_callable=map_manufacturer_model,
        op_kwargs={'s':'stringValue'}
    )
```

See the python operator example here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html

Comment: So that worked but now im getting the error Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable? There is no JSON code in my python script? I can always open a new question if not haha

Comment: Glad this worked, please consider marking correct and upvoting.  I would suggest going ahead and open up a new one for that one.